# Entire set of objects snapping to rotation instead of single object

Tags: animation

I have a problem and I'm not too well versed with blender.

I would like to rotate each individual wing to a certain degree during animation. However when I rotate one wing and then move to a different frame, the body and other 3 wings snap to the same location. The wings and body are each separate objects and they follow a bezier curve path.

![From individually rotated wings to any next/prev frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFH52.png

EDIT: Whoops sorry forgot to attach the file, I do believe it is up: [image]

To be specific I'd like the wings to rotate open at around frame 150-160

Comment: maybe share your object, or at least its armature: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

A friend had told me that the body and wings were sharing one animation so I had to make a new action and key frame the wings separately.